# How to use Git GUI from Unix using Xming

Tags: git, merge, xserver, git-gui, xming

I'm using Windows XP and I log in to a unix system using Putty where I run several Git commands. I have also installed Xming + Git GUI in my Windows system.

Now is it possible to use the Git GUI installed in my windows from the Unix system I login? For instance, if I give, `git diff` can it open the visual difference in my Windows Git GUI?

Comment: Do you mean using your native windows executable, or a unix gui shown over the X server?  The former is only possible if you mount the unix drive on your windows machine and run the command from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out lately.. This is what I did,

1. I have started xming and the putty (with X11 forwarding enabled)
2. Then after login to Unix, i set the DISPLAY environment variable to my localIP:0.0 (xming port)
3. Then I have the command, git difftool HEAD myfilename, which opened the p4Merge (which i had already installed in my windows) and showed the different in GUI.

Comment: Actually, if X11 forwarding was working, you wouldn't need to futz with `DISPLAY` -- the SSH server would start an X "proxy" and set `DISPLAY` up for you. However, the default configuration for the OpenSSH `sshd` has this feature disabled; see the `sshd_config(5)` manpage.

Comment: How can this be possible? You are having your git on Linux calling p4Merge on windows?